# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Tags: java, android, xml

please help me. my android project is showing this error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

how to solve this problem?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.gurujibd.ajkerkhobor"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
}
```

Comment: use [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) library i hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

First change all `28+` to `28.0.0-alpha3` or lower version like `27.1.1`

Then change `9.0.2` to latest version `15.0.0`